# Custom soft delete column and value for Eloquent ORM

Tags: php, orm, eloquent

I'm in the process of rewriting a REST service, and I've decided to go with Slim Framework and I'm using Eloquent ORM because it works best for me.

Previously I have done my soft deletes with a column `deleted` and set it to either 1 or 0 for deleted or not.

With Eloquent it sets a timsestamp to a column `deleted_at`, is there a way I can set it to my previous soft delete method of just setting deleted to 1?

Comment: Either use generic `SoftDelete` without its features concerning `deleted_at` timestamp (it will just work, there will be `null` values and not-null values) - but you need to make the field nullable. Or copy the `SoftDeletingScope` and create your own - you can read howto here: [softonsofa.com/laravel-how-to-define-global-scope](http://softonsofa.com/laravel-how-to-define-and-use-eloquent-global-scopes/)

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk Thanks. That's exactly what I needed, now I'm having an issue so I'm doing an insert using Eloquent and I guess it's expecting the columns `created_at`, `updated_at` which don't exist in my case. Is there anyway to get Eloquent to easily forget those columns?

Comment: `protected $timestamps = false;` http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#timestamps Also you need this `const DELETED_AT = 'deleted';`

Comment: Yeah, check the edit in my comment

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".