# Use custom soft deleted column in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I know that How can I use Soft Deleting feature for models in laravel. like this :

```
class Flight extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
}
```

But I want to use a custom column named `sender_deleted_at` for that feature where all related methods like `forceDelete` , `restore` , `withTrashed` and etc work based that column.

I wrote [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27910953/custom-soft-delete-column-and-value-for-eloquent-orm) But I could not get the right answer.

I'm using Laravel 5.3.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The SoftDeletes trait uses this code to "delete" a row:

```
protected function runSoftDelete() {
        $query = $this->newQueryWithoutScopes()->where($this->getKeyName(), $this->getKey());
        $this->{$this->getDeletedAtColumn()} = $time = $this->freshTimestamp();
        $query->update([$this->getDeletedAtColumn() => $this->fromDateTime($time)]);
}
```

The body of `getDeletedAtColumn()` is:

```
public function getDeletedAtColumn() {
    return defined('static::DELETED_AT') ? static::DELETED_AT : 'deleted_at';
}
```

Therefore you can do this:

```
class Flight extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;    
    protected $dates = ['my_deleted_at'];
    const DELETED_AT = 'my_deleted_at';
}
```

Answer (score 14):

**Short Answer:** Just declare a `const DELETED_AT` in your model and give it a column name you want to use.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    use Notifiable;

    const DELETED_AT = 'deletedAt';
}
```

**Explanation:** Well if you look at method `getDeletedAtColumn` in `trait Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes`

```
/**
 * Get the name of the "deleted at" column.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getDeletedAtColumn()
{
    return defined('static::DELETED_AT') ? static::DELETED_AT : 'deleted_at';
}
```

It's actually checking if you've declared a constant name `DELETED_AT` in your implementing class than get that value and if you haven't simply use `deleted_at` as a soft delete column.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, But i did not understand what is `static::DELETED_AT`. is it enough to change `deleted_at` term to my desired name?

Comment: This is declaring constant in the class which hold the column namr

Comment: This is the correct answer. Simple and works with the intention of the framework.